# When running a pygame script as root, no sound is output?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, sudo, raspberry-pi

I have written a very simple script for my raspberry pi that loads an uncompressed WAV and plays it - however when I run the script as root (to be able to use `GPIO` and `ServoBlaster`), there is no sound output.

I have set the default audio device to a USB sound card, and this works - I have tested this using `aplay fx.wav`.
Running the pygame script without `sudo`, the sound plays fine.

What is going on here?

Comment: how do you load your wav? absolute or relative path?

Comment: Relative - however no error is printed to the console, so it would appear as if it is finding it. I will attempt absolute once I have access to the Raspberry Pi again.

Comment: I would have thought that pygame would load from the script directory rather than the current one. Are relative paths loaded from the current user's home directory? And in which case, would running python with `sudo -s` fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the `sudo` command changing the directory in which the script was being run - so running python with `sudo -s` or simply using an absolute path for the sound fixed it.