# Running Python using sudo fails to play sound file

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to run a python script that both plays a sound (using pygame) and uses the onboard GPIO. I know to access the GPIO the script must be ran using sudo, but I've noticed that using `sudo python myscript.py` the code executes, but does not play the sound. Using `python myscript.py` the sound plays, but obviously the not GPIO. I've tried changing where I am referencing the audio file to an absolute path to no avail, I'm not overly familiar with inner workings of sudo, can anyone shed some light on this problem?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("alert.wav") 
pygame.mixer.music.play() 
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue

    GPIO.output(16,True)
    GPIO.output(18,True)
```

Output of `printenv`

```
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.0.114 64152 192.168.0.196 22
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
INFINALITY_FT_CHROMEOS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH=0
INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_INCREASE_GLYPH_HEIGHTS=true
INFINALITY_FT_CONTRAST=0
INFINALITY_FT_STEM_FITTING_STRENGTH=25
INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE=0
XDG_SESSION_ID=c5
USER=pi
INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_SNAP_STEM_HEIGHT=100
INFINALITY_FT_GRAYSCALE_FILTER_STRENGTH=0
INFINALITY_FT_GAMMA_CORRECTION=0 100
PWD=/home/pi
HOME=/home/pi
TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.0.114 64152 22
INFINALITY_FT_WINDOWS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH=10
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
INFINALITY_FT_BRIGHTNESS=0
MAIL=/var/mail/pi
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
INFINALITY_FT_USE_VARIOUS_TWEAKS=true
SHLVL=1
INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE=0
INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE=0
INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_HORIZONTAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH=10
LOGNAME=pi
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
INFINALITY_FT_FILTER_PARAMS=11 22 38 22 11
INFINALITY_FT_USE_KNOWN_SETTINGS_ON_SELECTED_FONTS=true
INFINALITY_FT_STEM_SNAPPING_SLIDING_SCALE=40
INFINALITY_FT_STEM_ALIGNMENT_STRENGTH=25
INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE=0
INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_VERTICAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH=25
INFINALITY_FT_FRINGE_FILTER_STRENGTH=0
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Output of `sudo printenv`

```
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
USERNAME=root
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/printenv
SUDO_USER=pi
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
```

Comment: Usually this happens because when you run the command with sudo, the environment variables are different, and on the basis of those something may not be set that you need to make it work.  Doing 'printenv' from the command line and then 'sudo printenv' will help you see what is different.  Adding that output to your question would be helpful

Comment: Instead of using `sudo`, you should fix the permission to the GPIO ports.

Comment: @JeffRichards I added the output of both `printenv` commands. I hope that helps you help me!

Comment: @KlausD. , I'm open to either method of getting this to work.

Comment: I would suggest, switching to the absolute path for the sound file, I know you said that you did that already, but I think it is the most likely culprit, since the home directories are changing when you run as sudo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When running a pygame script as root, no sound is output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405082/when-running-a-pygame-script-as-root-no-sound-is-output)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that doesn't require `sudo`, would be to create and use a `gpio` group. On raspbian, you can create a new group with `groupadd`.

Assign that group to the gpio devices with group read/write access for that group. You can do that with `chown`, but that won't last after a reboot.
On raspbian this is done with *permanently* a `udev` rule. See e.g. [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147494/how-can-i-set-device-rw-permissions-permanently-on-raspbian).

Then add the user-id that runs the Python programs to that group. On Raspbian this is done with `adduser`.

Note that if you're not running the raspbian distribution, the names of the relevant commands might be different.

With this set-up every user that is part of the `gpio` group can access the GPIO devices.